# Best way to store and fetch image bytes?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, storage

I have a case in my startup where I need to fetch images in bytes as fast as possible.

At the moment I'm storing the images in Azure Storage then I fetch them on the run and cache them into my database as bytes. On future requests these bytes will be fetched from the database directly. Fetching the bytes from the database is much faster, however, overtime it accumulated and now my database storage is 80% used.

My database is also on Azure and reserving more size will be expensive, so I'm looking into a better cheap way to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean by "fetch images *in bytes*"? Specifically the "in bytes" part? Do you mean you only need to fetch part of the image? Or the whole image?

Comment: @Schwern the whole image but will be used as bytes. What I mean is that I don't need to be .png or served as an any image type

Comment: Is this a web server?

Comment: How big are the images? IMHO, using database to cache blob storage data defeats the whole purpose of having images in blob storage.

Comment: @Schwern Yes it's

Comment: They are small maximum 30kb but fetching them from Azure Storage was slow so had to use db; even using cdn

Comment: Everything you send over the internet is measured in 'bytes'.

Comment: @Evert I need to fetch & use them as string bytes if that makes sense

Comment: If anyone is struggling with the same issue; please refer to here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/431199/best-way-to-store-and-fetch-image-bytes?noredirect=1#comment946827_431199

Comment: @Faisal You can, and are encouraged to, answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't cache large files in a database; databases are slow and storage is expensive and they are a limited resource. Cache them on disk; disk is *relatively* fast and cheap. Store only the path to the cached image in the database.

Do not open the file in your application and then stream it to the user; let your server serve the image directly from the file. This will be faster and use less resources; your server is very good at streaming files. It may be possible to [serve the files directly from Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website), then you don't need a cache.

Make sure the [cache headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) are set correctly on your responses. Then the request can use the cached version and save you from having to re-serve the image at all.

You may not have persistent file storage, that's fine, it's a cache and it can go away and get repopulated. You *do* need to have the same file storage for all your processes. For example, [Heroku's ephemeral file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) would not work as a file cache. You'd need some other shared file storage.

Comment: The way to do it was to directly fetch bytes from Azure Storage using DownloadToByteArray. I was downloading data using the image link instead and it was slow. Thanks for your help